# How to insert numbers in a column based upon time in another column using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a large csv file with format below:

```
date                               event-type          case         event
2020-07-23 00:00:00.000257032       wake-up                0         patient wakes
2020-07-23 10:30:00.005042270       meal                   1         patient has breakfast
2020-07-23 10:32:30.088683558       lavatory               2         1st - sample collected
```

I have around 600k entries like this.

The values in the case column doesn't exist beforehand.

The question is - with every changing minute in time in the date column, how to insert a unique number in the case column like:

```
date                              case
2020-07-23 10:30:00.005042270        1
2020-07-23 10:31:00.005042270        2
2020-07-23 10:32:00.005042270        3
```

Also, apart from the change in minute, all other changes are to be ignored i.e. say as long as time in date column is 10:30 the number entered in the rows in case column continues to be 1 until 10:31 appears in the date column.

Being new to python, I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
date_to_minute = df['date'].map(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d[:-3],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
previous_date_time = date_to_minute[0]
#if you want case column to start from 1, change this variable to 1
current_case = 0
cases = []
for current_date_time in date_to_minute:
    if current_date_time > previous_date_time:
        current_case += 1
    cases.append(current_case)
    previous_date_time = current_date_time #missed adding this line previously
df['cases'] = pd.Series(cases, name='cases')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but, the output is not as what I mentioned. I need the case number to change only when the minutes are changing, however, according to this solution, after a certain time the case numbers changes with every row - which is not intented

Comment: I missed adding a line, I have updated the solution now. Please try again

Comment: wow! thanks a lot - this works. Can you also suggest me how to incorporate the option of find and replace as used in excel in pandas? Like I have 'lavatory' and 'lavatory_volume' which is the same thing, so I want to use one word for it. Overall - thanks a lot really.

Comment: For that you can simply use the `replace` function on each column like so: `df['column1'].str.replace('lavatory', 'new_name')` and `df['column1'].str.replace('lavatory_volume', 'new_name')`.
Please be sure to mark your question answered!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your dataframe is sorted by `date`. Try this:

```
# pandas store Timestamp internally as nanosecond
# You first need to convert it to minutes since epoch (Jan 1, 1970)
minutes = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).astype('int64') // (60 * 10**9)

# Every new minute makes a new case number
df['case'] = minutes.diff().gt(0).cumsum()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, It raises a value error - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2020-07-23 00:00:00.000257032'

Comment: Your date column is string, not Timestamp. Try `minutes = pd.to_datetime(df[`date`]).astype....`.